# ASP.NET Repeater template sub-control visibility before databind

Tags: asp.net, repeater, findcontrol

I have a custom control which contains a Repeater control. The Repeater has an ItemTemplate. Inside that item template I have a panel which is going to hide something based on "IsEditable" a boolean property of the custom control. What I would like to do is set the panel's visibility once before the Repeater is databound.

I know I could do an onItemDataBound event and use FindControl to get the panel but that seems a little excessive since it will always be either visible or not for all rows and I have no other actions that need to occur on databind.

Is there a way to find the control in the ItemTemplate before the Repeater is databound?

Comment: I think it's best to rephrase the question since you're not asking something about a repeater control but about a Gridview.

Comment: Sorry it is a repeater. I was being dumb and typed it wrong. I updated the post.

Comment: I am confused because before a repeater is databound, it is empty. There aren't any controls inside of the Repeater that "exist" yet because it's not bound to anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Panel Visible='<%# this.IsEditable %>' runat="server">
        editableStuff
    </asp:Panel>
</ItemTemplate>
```